# Modifying only one file in a github stored project

Tags: git, github

Although I use git to manage my projects locally, I have started lately to use github. Forgive me if I mistake the terminology but I usually fork a project, then clone it to my local system. I do the changes then I push it to my github repository. Later I am supposed to do  a pull request

Is this the correct way of doing things, even when I have to do changes in only one file in a project with many files? Is that the only way?

Comment: *I usually fork a project, then clone it to my local system* Very well, that the exact termins!

Comment: *Is this the correct way … the only way?* It's a correct way and the most popular one. It's not the only way. Git is rather flexible.

Answer (score 1):

It is, provided the original repo is not one you have created (ie, you are not the owner of the created repo).

If you are the owner of the created repo, you can simply clone it directly, modify it, commit and push back. No PR involved.

Comment: In this case, I am not the ownder of the repo, and I have to modify the file. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @KansaiRobot If you are *not* the owner, then fork + PR is the official way. Another would be to open an issue, with a format-patch (https://github.com/cloudius-systems/osv/wiki/Formatting-and-sending-patches) copied in it, and see if the maintainer accepts it that way... but he/she might not.

Answer (score 1):

You may do it directly inside github.

Go to your fork -> navigate to the file you want to edit -> you'll see on the upper right corner the icon of a pencil that allows you to edit the file.

From there you may edit you file, commit and pull request all from inside github without having to clone your project locally